# Connect online mysql database with the local xampp server using php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I tried using the following code in php:

```
<?php
$servername = "www.psgcirdask.com";
$username = "xxx"; //hidden for security purpose
$password = "password";
$dbname = "psgcilqh_calibration";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM brands";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
$conn->close();
?>
```

I got an error:

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'xxx'@'157.51.147.43' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\justshawarmapos\checkthedatabase.php on line 9
>       Connection failed: Access denied for user 'xxx'@'157.51.147.43' (using password: YES)

But i use the same username and password to connect to my database in my website.I am getting this problem only when i connect using local server.

Comment: Your web site does not connect from `157.51.147.43`, does it?

Comment: Yeah this is my ip address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable remote access in your mysql database.

Check this [link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql&ved=2ahUKEwjSirPuuq3bAhUFSX0KHXDLBS0QFjADegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw1xxJpuqnGPsEA7aLezXM5B)

For [hostgator](https://youtu.be/xXOq9U9fzOo)

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: @NikeshhBaskaran maybe https://serverfault.com/questions/52794/how-do-i-allow-remote-access-to-mysql-using-xampp helps

Comment: My website is on hostgator.How to do it there?

Comment: That's even easier from hostgator cpanel : https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DxXOq9U9fzOo&ved=0ahUKEwivwPyGvK3bAhWWYysKHZ_bAUQQFggrMAE&usg=AOvVaw1ggbFMQspEOz9yjR0VY39l

Comment: I added my ip address 157.51.171.108 in the remote access but still i get the same error

Comment: $servername = "www.psgcirdask.com"; Is this correct or should i change it?

Comment: If that is your domain name where the database is in, yes use your domain name.

Comment: Hmmmm... in allow access input field % try that from c panel mysql remote settings. Also check your credential again.

Comment: I copy pasted the credentials from a working code from my website.

Comment: I am trying to move my discussion to chat. Since i am having less reputations i am not able to move.

Comment: Got it.Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Check if all the infos provided are correct especially the servername then try to figure out if you have the right permission to access that database with that user!