# Unable to connect Website to my phpmyadmin MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, web-hosting

Before I get into the question, I ran into a lot of questions, both on this website, as well as a bunch of others, however none of the solutions there helped, and so decided to post a question with my exact situation.

So I am currently building a website, and am trying to connect it to a MySQL database I have created on phpmyadmin through hostgator. I am currently using 000webhost.com to host my webpages, as the computer I am working on does not have an ftp client, and am unable to install it as of now. As such, I decided to upload the files onto there temporarily as I build it, as they are dynamic webpages. Whenever I load up the page, however, I receive this error:

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): ProxySQL Error: Access denied for user...

where the "..." just lists my username and filepath to the file.

this is my php code to connect to the database:

```
<?php
define("DB_SERVER","localhost");
define("DB_USERNAME","**user**");
define("DB_PASSWORD","**password**");
define("DB_DATABASE","**database_name**");
if(!mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD)){
    echo"Failure";
}
else{
    echo"Success!";
}
?>
```

I double- and triple-checked the database username, password and name, however to no avail. Thanks a lot in advanced!

Comment: Please, ALWAYS show us ALL the error message. If you summarise it we loose possibly vital information

Comment: Did you check all those parameters with the CPanel settings

Comment: Do this search on Google `000webhost Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): ProxySQL Error: Access denied for user` and you will see a bunch of similiar question on the 000webhost help system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your DB Server location due to you are not using the same web server as your hosting. 
Change this 
`define("DB_SERVER","localhost");` to `define("DB_SERVER","YOUR_REMOTE_DB_SERVER");`
Also you have to enable remote access in your mysql database.
You can check this [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50604876/connect-online-mysql-database-with-the-local-xampp-server-using-php)

Comment: Even if you change the settings to the remote ones, please make sure your MySQL server allows remote access. Otherwise it will not work

Comment: Huh such a simple fix. I moved the files onto my HostGator file manager, without changing any of the contents, and it works flawlessly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your initial question, there is no call to connect.

```
define("DB_SERVER","localhost");
define("DB_USERNAME","**user**");
define("DB_PASSWORD","**password**");
define("DB_DATABASE","**database_name**");

$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
```

then test your connection.

As for setting up a localhost for development, if you are using Windows I would suggest XAMPP, it is pretty much download and say yes to all.